# 404 on old link after changing post url

Tags: php, permalinks, redirect, seo

Hello I have a problem where i have 404 on posts after changing url with php using this function

```
wp_update_post( array(
                    'ID' => $post_id,
                    'post_name' => $new_slug
                ));
```

This happens in cases like the example below

if original post link abc.com/how-to-example
if I change to abc.com/how-to-example-passwd  <-- redirect will still work
and I change again to a new permalink for third time redirect will work only for original link and new link and changes made between those two will return 404

Is it possible to keep all changes and make them redirect to current post using php?
I noticed wp automatically keep a custom field for the original link only

Comment: Why are you doing this? This appears to be a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the following code in your `htaccess`.

`Redirect 301 <Old Url> <New Url>`

Place old link of your post in place of `<Old Url>` and new link in place of `<New Url>`

For reference view this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030491/redirect-one-url-to-another-url-using-htaccess).

Comment: but i have tens of thousands of posts and permalinks might change frequently sometimes i might change 200 in a day also im using nginx

Comment: You can try {https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/} plugin. It will help you to manage the redirections.